# How to add html elements inside $.each inside .append() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is the jQuery code to append HTML inside a table. It returns this error

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

```
    $('#table').append('<tr><td class="column">'+
          $.each(phone_no, function (idx, elem){
           +'<input class="phone" name="phone[0]" value="'+elem+'" />'
         +})+
        '<a href="'+data['url']+'" target="_blank">'+
        '<span class="fas fa-external-link-alt" style="color:#222;"></span>'+
        '</a></td></tr>');
```

What is the correct way to add this HTML inside `$.each` in `append()`?

If I use this then there is no error but the input fields does not show.

```
$('#table').append('<tr><td class="column">'
+$.each(phone_no, function (idx, elem){'<input class="phone" name="phone[0]" value="'+elem+'" />'
})+
'<a href="'+data['url']+'" target="_blank">'+
'<span class="fas fa-external-link-alt" style="color:#222;"></span></a></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Maybe build a variable with all the html and then append it to the table?

Comment: let me try that

Comment: @FunkDoc building a variable with all the html and then append it to the table *did not* work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a function with string concatenation like that, try and separate your logic like this:

```js
var html = '<tr><td class="column">';
$.each(phone_no, function(idx, elem) {
  html += '<input class="phone" name="phone[0]" value="' + elem + '" />';
});
html += '<a href="' + data['url'] + '" target="_blank">' +
  '<span class="fas fa-external-link-alt" style="color:#222;"></span>' +
  '</a></td></tr>';
$('#table').append(html);
```